# Network Recycle Bin - Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a headless Ubuntu Lucid LTS server (Ubuntu 10.04). Network recycle bin is implemented client side on Linux desktops for files deleted via the GUI.

What can I install/configure to extend this functionality to files deleted from the command line, or from non-Linux clients i.e. Windows, Mac, Phones, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the service. IF you are deleting from command line you can make a bash alias so rm would map to mv file to a directory designed for the recycle bin.
If the clients are using samba to access files on the server then there is a samba module called recycle that creates a network recycle bin.